# facebook graph api photos retrieve

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to know how I can retrieve all photos of a page in facebook. I have tried

1. https://graph.facebook.com/(page name here)/albums?access_token=(token key here)
2. https://graph.facebook.com/(page name )/photos?access_token=

But 2. brings only photos that are under profile pictures I want all pictures of that page.

Comment: I'm just running up against this now too; it seems that `/me/photos` (or where the object ID refers to a person) returns tagged photos, but `/myPage/photos` does not. At least, not by default... Is there a certain permission that needs to be enabled here?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a "page access token" rather than a "user access token". See "Page login" section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Nope. This does not work. I have the same issue and I am using a page access token, not a user access token. Call only returns images that were previously used as profile pictures.

Comment: Odd, I was making it work at the time of writing my response on Jan 4th.  As you may be aware, facebook is ALWAYS changing things.